Inflation effects of linear income tax with grant
I have been reading The Theory of Taxation and Public Economics by Kaplow.
A linear income tax is described by the function:
$$T(wl) = twl - g$$
where t is the marginal tax rate, $wl$ is the income for some labour and $g$ is a grant given to people that earn $0$ ($T(0) = -g$).
I am curious to know if there are studies of inflationary effects of the grant (where $T(wl) < 0$) in an economy that only has income tax.
Because of consumption preferences being different for lower income indiviuals, and because of correlations between income and ability to do work, my intuition says that there could be inflationary effects for some goods and services and deflationary effects for others (like financial products and services?).
Another view would be that the net effect is neutralized as spending moves around in the economy, resulting in some investment (in production, etc) that works to undo the inflationary effects (say producing more, or changing employment/income dynamics to counteract this effect).
Is there a more in depth analysis of the effects of the transfer? Does it have a clear inflationary effect in the short and medium term? Does it favor some "stable" imbalance in the real economy?
Thanks!
